# Cell with 2 labels always is 'unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints'

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a cell with 2 simple labels, and I have been working the last 6 hours to get it working (had it working before that and decided to tinker with it and lost my working version). I always get a `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.` Warning. Here is the warning I get when I use the recommended constraints:

```
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8fe8737520 V:[UILabel:0x7f8fe873d5a0'Label'(26)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8fe8738ea0 UILabel:0x7f8fe873d7a0'Label'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8fe873cf00.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8fe8739000 UILabel:0x7f8fe873d5a0'Label'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8fe873cf00.bottomMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8fe8739110 V:[UILabel:0x7f8fe873d7a0'Label']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7f8fe873d5a0'Label']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8fe8743ac0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8fe873cf00(43.6667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8fe8737520 V:[UILabel:0x7f8fe873d5a0'Label'(26)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Here is my prototype cell in the storyboard (it is custom if you didn't already figure that out by now):
[image]

The small label in the bottom right is 'Sayer' and the larger one is 'Body'.

***Edit***: As a side note I do not want to constrain the height of body as it is a label whose height varies depending on the amount of text in it.

***Edit 2***: The warning disappeared using the solution provided by @siburb . But a new problem persists as shown in the above screen show body is a large UILabel for which I have set the `lines` property equal to `0` as that is supposed to allow the label to vary its size based on the amount of text input. When I run the program though (in screen shot below) I can only see the sayer UILabel. The body label has text in it (I tested it) so that is not the issue.

[image]

And in my `RecentTableViewController.h` (the file for this table view) I have included the method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Which was supposed to dynamically size the UILabel, I had it working before in this exact setup but my constraints got messed up and not it is not working.

***Edit 3***: Here is the picture of the working version after adding the suggested edits to my code in the ***Edit*** section of @siburb response.

[image]

Comment: You have constrained the height of `Sayer` to 26 but it's height is also set by top/bottom constraints so there is a conflict.  Auto layout is breaking the height=26 constraint to resolve the conflict.  Either remove the height constraint or the top or bottom constraints or set priorities on the constraints so that auto layout knows which is more important

Comment: @brettf - I've added further information to my answer below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the "priority" on one of the constraints.

Try reducing the priority of the bottom constraint of "body" to 900 - this will mean that the height constraint of "sayer" won't be broken.

Also, it might help to reduce the "Vertical Content Hugging Priority" of the "body" UILabel to 1 - this will mean the "body" UILabel won't be so keen to stick to the height of its "intrinsic content size" (the size dictated by the content of the label).

**EDIT:** To fix the second issue, you may need to increase the "**Vertical** Content Compression Resistance Priority" of the "body" UILabel. For example, increase it to 999.

You also don't need to have the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Just include something like the following in your `viewDidLoad:` method:

`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Comment: I reduced the priorities for both the bottom of body and the Vertical Hugging of body, there are no run time warnings thrown like before, though the cell still doesn't show up like it should, since that is a different issue, I will accept this answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks. It's related to this issue, so add another screenshot if you want and I'm happy to give further advice.

Comment: Ok will add a screen shot.

Comment: Screenshot and additional information were added under ***Edit 2*** @siburb